# Запись в txt файл в определенную строку и считывание этой записи

Tags: файлы, php

Добрый день.

Есть текстовый файл, в нем много чего записано. Про операции с текстовыми файлами нашел информацию в стиле создать/удалить, записать/вывести

1. Как в строку, скажем 5 записать определенную переменную, или стереть от туда все? (к сожалению увидел только просто запись в файл и все)
2. Как считать из этого файла строку номер 5? не весь файл, а только 1 строку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что бы  считать 5 строку, нужно впустую прочитать 4 строки. Да, это медленно, но если хочется сразу читать 5 строку, то нужно создавать некий индекс, где будут записаны смещения строк. Потом, имея такой индекс, можно перейти к нужной позиции с помощью [fseek](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php) и сразу читать строку.

Если нужно просто заменить пятую строку своей строкой, то тут не все так просто. Если длина вставляемой строки и строки в файле совпадает, то можно просто перетереть (опять же fseek перемещает на нужную позицию, fwrite  пишет). Если новая строка короче, то в файле будет хвост от старой.

Но если нужно удалить строку с файла, то тут только обычно делают так - вначале перемещаются до начала изменений, а потом блоками переписывают хвост, затирая строку. В самом конце делают укорочения файла.

Если у Вас возникают такие вопросы, то может быть Вам нужна база данных? Не обязательно MySQL, можно и sqlite.

Comment: оба ответа хороши, но принимаю этот, т.к. больше понятно что самому делать ручками и в какой последовательности

Answer (score 2):

[for](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.for.php), [file](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file.php)